# Google V8: access local variables in C++

Tags: c++, v8

Does someone know how I could look up local variables in a nested function call from C++?
Consider the following example:

```
// e.g. a global variable in the browser
var global = "global_value";

function foo(){
    var global = "local_value";
    myCppFunction("global", global);
}

foo();
```

My question now is how in the implementation of `myCppFunction` I could access the function local variable "global" (NOT value, this would be given by the 2nd parameter) from 'foo'?

```
Handle<Value> MyCppFunction(const Arguments& args){
    Local<String> varName = args[0]->ToString();
    Local<String> varValue = args[1]->ToString(); // this holds "local_value"
    // how to access the variable "global" in the scope of 'foo' ?
}
```

Comment: You can only send global variable, something like `myCppFunction("global", ::global);`

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that I'm modifying V8 (in this case I rewrite the AST of 'foo' and insert a call to my C++ function) and thus also can access the internal data structures if necessary for this task. I just don't know where to look that up - or whether it is really not possible during runtime by the way V8 is designed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find it out by myself. See the example below for how to find the value on the stack (and also replace it - here by the example of a string variable).

Two remarks beforehand:

- I have not tested this for undesired behavior except from my very use cases where I use this in my master thesis - there (may) be dragons.
- I don't know exactly why in my tests `sfl.FindJavaScriptFrame(0)` yields the desired stack frame - but, as it works independently of the calling depth, I suspect the stack frame indexed by 0 to always be the immediate caller's frame (in my case I know that I want exactly that).

And the code:

```
// Prepare identification of the variable,assuming varName as in the question
// More convenient conversions would be appreciated, at least by me
Local<String> varName = args[0]->ToString();        
std::string varStr = *String::AsciiValue(varName);
// I'm using 'namespace i = internal;' (within v8-namespace)
i::Vector<const char> tmpVar(varStr.data(), varStr.length());
i::Handle<i::String> varIStr = i::Isolate::Current()->factory()->NewStringFromAscii(tmpVar, i::TENURED);

// Now hunt down the stack frame of interest, be sure to consider my remarks above
i::StackFrameLocator sfl;
// Comment from the code: The caller must guarantee that such a frame exists.
i::JavaScriptFrame* jsf = sfl.FindJavaScriptFrame(0);
// create some replacement
i::Vector<const char> tmp("there you go", 12);
i::Handle<i::String> insert = i::Isolate::Current()->factory()->NewStringFromAscii(tmp, i::TENURED);
i::Object* insertObj = insert->ToObjectChecked();

// by the help of JavaScriptFrame::Print I came up with this:
i::Object* fun = jsf->function();
if (fun->IsJSFunction()){
    i::Handle<i::ScopeInfo> scope_info(i::ScopeInfo::Empty());
    i::Handle<i::SharedFunctionInfo> shared((i::JSFunction::cast(fun))->shared());
    scope_info = i::Handle<i::ScopeInfo>(shared->scope_info());
    i::Object* script_obj = shared->script();
    if (script_obj->IsScript()) {
        int stack_locals_count = scope_info->StackLocalCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < stack_locals_count; i++) {
            if (scope_info->StackLocalName(i)->Equals(*varIStr)){
                // replace the value on the stack
                jsf->SetExpression(i,insertObj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the same code still work with the latest V8? What headers are you including?

Comment: I can't tell you, I haven't had a look at it since then. But it probably won't work exactly this way anymore as it is coupled with V8 internals which are not exposed and hence not meant to be accessed by V8 users that just embed it in a project.
I integrated this sort of access directly into V8 as an approach to investigate how/whether information flow tracking could be implemented for JavaScript. To point it out, this was only experimental and never used and tested for production.
If you want to play around with this, you need to build your own modified version of V8 which exposes this.